# PHP SimpleXML not parsing &lt;

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

For some reason SimpleXML is not parsing `&lt;ADMIN&gt;`.

My XML file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE client-config SYSTEM "asigra_conf_windows.dtd">
<notifications>
    <email-notification recipient="&lt;ADMIN&gt;"/>
</notifications>
```

Code that reads the XML file:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/test/xml.xml');

    echo "Recipient:". $xml['email-notification']['@attributes']['recipient'];
```

Output is Recipient: "blank"

How can I make it read the ADMIN from `&lt;ADMIN&gt;` ?

I'm using xampp with Apache and PHP 5.6.

Comment: or the entire `&lt;ADMIN&gt;`

Comment: $xml->children()[0]->attributes()['recipient']

Comment: $xml_string->children()[0]->attributes()['recipient'] is displaying as blank. If I do Inspect Element in Firefox, I can see `<admin></admin>`.

Comment: instead of inspecting try viewing the source of your page or execute your script from the command line

Comment: Strange, Page Source is displaying `Recipient:<ADMIN>`. How do I make it visible ?

Comment: print_r is showing a blank space and var_dump says string(7) and then blank. But I can see the `<ADMIN>` in Page Source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for you assistance (especially IMSoP, you were right about htmlspecialchars).

The reason I kept failing was because I was reinforcing the stereotype of man not reading the manual.

I just had to spend 5 minutes looking at the examples @ http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php. It also explains why you should not use json_encode/decode.

For other tl;dr people, here are some examples of the code that I am using now:

When I have XML that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <setup-config>
        <account-name>Trump</account-name>
    </setup-config>
<configuration>
```

↴

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/config.xml');

echo $xml->{'configuration'}->{'setup-config'}->{'account-name'};
```

When I have XML that looks like this:

```
<configuration>
    <setup-config>
        <user-info country-code="826"/>
    </setup-config>
<configuration>
```

↴

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/config.xml');

echo $xml->{'configuration'}->{'setup-config'}->{'user-info'}['country-code'];
```

When I have XML with HTML chars:

```
<configuration>
    <defaults-config>
        <def-notification name="&lt;ADMIN&gt;"/>
    </defaults-config>
</configuration>
```

↴

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/config.xml');

echo htmlspecialchars($xml->{'configuration'}->{'defaults-config'}->{'def-notification'}['name']);
```

Iterating:

```
<configuration>
    <roles-config>
        <group-role role="administrator" name="Administrators" from="."/>
        <group-role role="backup-operator" name="Backup Operators" from="."/>
    </roles-config>
</configuration>
```

↴

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/config.xml');

foreach ($xml->{'configuration'}->{'roles-config'}->{'group-role'} as $grouproles => $groles) {
    echo "<tr><td>group role name: ".$groles['name']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>group role role: ".$groles['role']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>group role role: ".$groles['from']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Simple existence check:

```
<configuration>
    <setup-config>
        <account-name>Trump</account-name>
    </setup-config>
<configuration>
```

↴

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://localhost/config.xml');

if(isset($xml->{'configuration'}->{'setup-config'}->{'account-name'})){
    echo $xml->{'configuration'}->{'setup-config'}->{'account-name'};
}
```